# SQL Server database security

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, t-sql

I have SQL Server 2008 installed on Windows 2008 Server.

I've disabled built-in administrator password and created `sa` with sysadmin privileges.

Question is: Is there any way to access to database, or back it up. or methods to reset (and / or) get password for `sa`?

I want to secure my database.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "secure" the database? Can't login? Can't backup? Can't execute queries? Can't read certain tables or schemas?

Comment: @Bridge revoke access from Built-in administrators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've disabled built-in administrator password...I want to secure my database.

If you think you can disable access to built-in administrators your are chasing a phantasm. Built-in administrators will **always** be able to access your database, the steps to gain access are clearly documented in [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx). Your database **must** be deployed on a system on which you completely trust the system administrators, there is no work around for this basic requirement.

Most often this question is asked as some misguided attempt to protect the perceived IP in the database. The answer to that question is that what you want is called DRM and SQL Server does not offer DRM. If you are afraid of distributing the database to your users then use a service like [SQL Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/sql-azure/).

Comment: what about if execute script "Turn off DBO and Single User mode for all DB's" http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/30490/

Comment: **Nothing** will work. Internalize it. Is just smoke and mirrors. The bar can be raised, one can say that locks are in place to keep honest people honest not to prevent thieves. But don't fool *yourself*. A system administrator has complete access to your database, if he chooses so. Period.

Answer (score 1):

Users who have to have access to the `SQLCmd` prompt would be be able to run perform such commands. You could access the database and reset passwords the console and do something like this:

```
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = ‘newpassword’ UNLOCK
```

Comment: The built-in account is disabled. So no user have access to SQLCMD.

Comment: @loviji - Then you will be fine.